# Parsing nessus HTTP response with Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm building a feature into the nessus-xmlrpc gem to allow HTML reports to be downloaded. I'm down to where I just need to just parse the HTML response for the fileName value.

Here is the example response I'm using, from nessus:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formatting the report</title><meta http-equiv="refresh"
content="5;url=/file/xslt/download/?fileName=Windows_-_Main___Media_kr1sjb.html">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2b4e67">
<link type="text/css" href="jqueryui18.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui18.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

When use Nokogiri:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(http_content)
```

The doc ends up like:

```
#<Nokogiri::HTML::Document:0x4758128 name="document" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::DTD:0x4757f48 name="html">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x47578ea name="html" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x47577aa name="head" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x475767e name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x475764c name="charset" value="utf-8">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x4757368 name="title" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x475723c "Formatting the report">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x475af9a name="meta" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x475ac48 name="http-equiv" value="refresh">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x475ac2a name="content" value="5;url=/file/xslt/download/?fileName=Windows_-_Main___Media_kr1sjb.html">]>]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x470b968 name="body" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x470b7ec name="bgcolor" value="#2b4e67">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x46fb216 name="link" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x46fb18a name="type" value="text/css">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x46fb176 name="href" value="jqueryui18.css">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x46fb16c name="rel" value="stylesheet">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x46fa1d6 name="script" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x46fa0e6 name="type" value="text/javascript">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x46fa0c8 name="src" value="jqueryui18.js">]>, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x46dd43c name="div" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x46dd37e name="id" value="main">]>]>]>]>
```

I can't figure out how to get the `fileName` value back, "Windows_-*Main*__Media_kr1sjb.html".

Any help would be wonderful and I  will push these change for all once it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eol
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Formatting the report</title><meta http-equiv="refresh"
content="5;url=/file/xslt/download/?fileName=Windows_-_Main___Media_kr1sjb.html">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#2b4e67">
<link type="text/css" href="jqueryui18.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui18.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
eol

str = doc.at_css('meta[http-equiv="refresh"]')['content']
# => "5;url=/file/xslt/download/?fileName=Windows_-_Main___Media_kr1sjb.html"
str[/\?fileName=(.*)/,1]
# => "Windows_-_Main___Media_kr1sjb.html"
```

Comment: Okay well I have to catch a response so I have the above html doc in a variable called http_content. How would I adjust your method to make it work as such?